# Different value in browser and in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Can someone please explain to me why in this code when I type a character the character that appears in the label tag is different from the character that appears on the console? Is the code correct?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [text, settext] = useState("");

  const update = (e) => {
    settext(e.target.value);
    console.log(text);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={text} onChange={update} />
      <label>{text}</label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `settext` doesn't update the `text` state instantly. So calling `console.log(text)` right after it will give interesting results.

What you want to use is [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to log out the value of `text`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [text, settext] = useState("");

  const update = (e) => {
    settext(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => console.log(text), [text]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={text} onChange={update} />{" "}
      <label> {text} </label>{" "}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```